# Ubuntu can't update

Tags: python

when I use `sudo update-manager -c -d` to update the system, it returns the following:

```
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 38, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 43, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are all your packages updated? `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: If you need to ask this question, reconsider using the -d flag. You may lack the skills to handle the consequences. `-d` will upgrade to the unstable, in-testing, pre-release version of 19.10...which we don't provide support for.

Answer (score 0):

To Update your Ubuntu do:
`sudo apt update` : Refreshes repository index
`sudo apt upgrade` : Upgrades all upgradable packages
This should upgrade all your current packages to the latest version.

If you are looking to upgrade your Ubuntu you can do that with :`sudo do-release-upgrade`
You can learn more about upgrading Ubuntu [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-to-18-04-lts-using-terminal/).

If none of them are working, then there is a good chance that there is some issue in your "sources.list" located in `/etc/apt/sources.list`